# Using Paperclip to upload a file from a backgound job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

We're using Paperclip to upload files to S3 by presenting a browse dialog to the user. That's works nice & smooth. However, now I wish  that some background job will do some crawling, and when it reaches a required file, upload that one as well. Obviously I can't use the browse dialog at this point.

All examples I saw for using Paperclip is about selecting the file manually from the client (by updating the view). I've failed to find how to set up the file to be uploaded by code, and since the UI component triggers some "behind the scenes" work that creates some object with additional information that I couldn't find how to use or call.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Paperclip Upload without using your browse dialog and an user action is also not required. Paperclip needs a file, simple generate a tmp file or use an existing file from your storage.

Your Paperclip model class:

```
class YourPaperclipmodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :data
end
```

Generate file:

```
YourPaperclipmodel.create(:data => File.open("path to existing file or tmp generated file"))
```

Comment: Already tried to, but it requires Reputation 15, which I don't yet have.

Comment: Ah ok, didn´t know that :). but now somebody else does it, thanks ;)